# Content Manager Thumbnail Cache and Missing Component Template Icon

Tags: experience-manager

I added an Icon for a Component Template, which didn't show in Experience Manager right away.

[image: The Event Component Template Icon didn't show]

After deleting cached images in %TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\ThumbnailCache, I was able to see the icon. But I think [updating the modification number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14668866/395495) would work as well (for script, styles, and images).

- **For these icons, is clearing the cache or incrementing the modification the "right" approach?**
- Is there something I can do to prevent ThumbnailCache from getting out of date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think at this moment is to install a Browser add-on that eliminates the cache for every request. It will of course affect XPM performance. I really don't see a huge impact on refreshing the cache when you change the icon since it will be done just once

Comment: Okay, yeah that's a bit much just for the icons. :-) I think the typical update process would be to set all the desired CT icons first, clear the thumbnail cache, and then test (rather than small changes).

Comment: Use Chrome Incognito?